Preserve the scroll position and paging data when switching tabs in Jetpack Compose
I have two tabs: Video and Magazine.
The screens for both tabs are identical, utilizing Jetpack Compose for the UI.
Data is fetched using the Paging 3 library from a common API endpoint, differentiated by a query parameter to return either a list of videos or magazines.
However, when switching between the tabs, the state is not retained—both the scroll state and the paging data are lost and starts from position 0 in the list.
How can I preserve the state (including scroll position and paging data) when switching tabs in Jetpack Compose?
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    categoryData: CategoryData?
) {

if (categoryData == null) {
    return
}

val items = categoryData.categories

val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { items.size })

var selectedTabIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = selectedTabIndex) {

    pagerState.scrollToPage(selectedTabIndex)
}


Box(
    Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {


    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        userScrollEnabled = false
    ) { page ->
        FeedScreen(selectedTabIndex, categoryData.categories[selectedTabIndex].id) {}
    }



    Box {


        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .scrollable(
                    state = rememberScrollState(),
                    orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                ),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(items) { index, currentTab ->

                CustomTab(currentTab.name, selectedTabIndex == index, index) { pos ->
                    selectedTabIndex = pos
                }
            }
        }


        }

    }
}`

This is my VerticalViewPager
@OptIn(
    ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class
)
@androidx.annotation.OptIn(androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi::class)
@Composable
fun FeedScreen(
  selectedTabIndex: Int,
  tabId: Int
) {
val viewModel: MainScreenViewModel = viewModel()
viewModel.requestedTabId = tabId


val feedItems = viewModel.feedItems.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { feedItems.itemCount })



VerticalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(LokalTheme.colors.baseBlack)
        .clickable(
            indication = null,
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
        }
        .zIndex(0f),
    beyondBoundsPageCount = 3,
) { page ->

    val item = feedItems[page]
    
    when (item) {
        is PostData.VideoData -> {
            //Display VideoCard
        }

        is PostData.MagazineCardData -> {
            //Display MagazineCard
        }
    }
  }
}

Tried saving the data in ViewModel to maintain the states but this did not work.
I'm expecting the tabs to retain their scroll position & data when we switch between them.
